# Assume that $a_{n+1}/a_n \rightarrow L$, where $L<1$ and $a_n>0$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing for $n \texttt{>>}1$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question 3(a)**: Assume that $a_{n+1}/a_n \rightarrow L$, where $L<1$ and $a_n>0$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing for $n \texttt{>>}1$
>
> > source: https://math.mit.edu/~choiks/Pset%202%20solutions.pdf[image]

My simple proof: Since $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} <  1$$, we can see that $$ a_{n+1} < a_n \text{,  for } n \texttt{>>}1$$ .
Is this correct?

This is trivial but I also don't understand in the solution $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq L + (1-L)$ for $n >>1,$ why it is $\leq$ instead of $<$. Isn't it clear that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ cannot be equal to $L$, let alone $L + (1-L)$ ?

Comment: You can make it a strict inequality. However, $a<b$ implies $a\leq b$. So it's not wrong to write as a non-strict inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1}/a_n \rightarrow L$. By definition, for all $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$ implies in $a_{n+1}/a_n < L + \epsilon$. But, by hypotesis, $L < 1 \Rightarrow 1-L > 0$ then you just need take $\epsilon = 1-L$.